# Git: merge branch A again to branch B

Tags: git, version-control, merge

We have a branch "master" for release, and a branch "develop" for development.

I have created a branch based on "develop" called "develop2", and made some modifications(commits).

The guys on branch "develop" also made some commits.

Now I want to get these new commits from branch "develop" to my branch "develop2", how should I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should you keep a shared develop branch up to date with upstream changes on git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058826/how-should-you-keep-a-shared-develop-branch-up-to-date-with-upstream-changes-on)

Comment: @Panda I think the issue described is indeed the same, but there is no concrete answer in the link provided; making it rather valueless?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can probably use command called `rebase`

Here is what you would do

1. Go to your branch `develop2`

   `git checkout develop2`
2. Make sure your are on branch `develop2`

   `git branch`
3. Run rebase

   `git rebase develop`

So what rebase will do is besically take the commit string on branch `develop2` and place it on top of branch `develop`, see image below

[image: rebase example]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should update your remote branches to download your friend's changes:
`git fetch`

Than rebase when you're on develop2 branch:
`git rebase origin/develop`

Alternatively, you can do it in one line:
`git pull --rebase origin develop`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Update your upstream branch information

```
git fetch
```

2) Setup your *develop2* branch to track your upstream *develop* branch

```
git branch -u origin/develop develop2
```

3) Go to develop2 branch (if you are not already there)

```
git checkout develop2
```

4) Apply your colleagues commits then your's on top of them

```
git pull --rebase
```

In this step if you have got any **conflict**s resolve them, then `git add .` to index em, and `git rebase --continue` to continue and finish rebasing